# How to turn water valve on to dishwasher

Tags: water, valve, dishwasher

We live in a rented house and  recently bought a dishwasher. The previous owners had a dishwasher in the same place so we know it works.

We have attached the waste pipe fine and think the water pipe is attached in the right place, but we can’t turn the water on as there isn’t a  handle on the valve. It looks like perhaps it may have come off.

How can we turn the water on?

Do we need to get a little spanner or am I on completely the wrong track?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 2):

Either get a new handle, or use a wrench on the flats of the valve shaft to turn it (just 1/4 turn, by the look of that valve.)